# How to declare the default value of an enumerated property?

Tags: c#, properties, default

How do i set the default value of an enumerated property?

e.g.:

```
public enum SearchBoxMode { Instant, Regular };


[DefaultValue(SearchBoxMode.Instant)]
public SearchBoxMode Mode { get { return mode; } set { mode = value;  } }    

[DefaultValue((int)SearchBoxMode.Instant)]
public SearchBoxMode Mode { get { return mode; } set { mode = value;  } }    

[DefaultValue(SearchBoxMode.GetType(), "Instant")]
public SearchBoxMode Mode { get { return mode; } set { mode = value;  } }    

[DefaultValue(SearchBoxMode.GetType(), "SearchBoxMode.Instant")]
public SearchBoxMode Mode { get { return mode; } set { mode = value;  } }
```

---

Unrelated question: How do i get the `Type` of an enumeration? e.g.

```
Type type = DialogResult.GetType();
```

does not work.

Comment: This code won't compile.  Attribute values must be constants.  They can't be function calls, variables, or computed values.

Comment: @Inuyaha i know the code doesn't work/compile - i was showing my (failed) attempts at "research effort". (Some people to refuse to answer a question unless it's padded with junk)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default value of an enum is 0 of the underyling type, even if 0 isn't **defined** for that enum.  Anything else must be done manually, for example:

```
SearchBoxMode mode = SearchBoxMode.Instant; // field initializer
```

Using `[DefaultValue(...)]` only impacts things like serialization and `PropertyGrid` - it doesn't actually make the property default to that value. The correct syntax is as per your first example:

```
SearchBoxMode mode = SearchBoxMode.Instant;
[DefaultValue(SearchBoxMode.Instant)]
public SearchBoxMode Mode { get { return mode; } set { mode = value;  } }
```

Another approach is a constructor:

```
[DefaultValue(SearchBoxMode.Instant)]
public SearchBoxMode Mode { get; set; }

public YourType() {
    Mode = SearchBoxMode.Instant;
}
```

re the second question; `typeof(DialogResult)`